# clone - using same javascript and css for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, duplicates, clone

First, I have an image and a title:

```
<!-- HTML code -->
<img class="gthumb" src="http://i.imgur.com/V9vL6kg.png" width="175"><div class="title">Grand Theft Auto IV<br/>俠盜獵車手IV</div>
```

Second, I hide the title by default:

```
// CSS code
.title { display: none; position: absolute; }
```

Third, I use jQuery to show the title when hovering the image:

```
// JS code
$("img.gthumb").hover (function () {
      $("div.title").show();
    }, function () {
      $("div.title").hide();
});
$("img.gthumb").mousemove(function(e) {
      var width = $('div.title').width();
      var height = $('div.title').height();
      $("div.title").css("top",e.pageY - height - 5);
      $("div.title").css("left",e.pageX - width / 2);
});
```

And then I clone the `HTML code` to display another group of image and title, the original title and the cloned title are overlapping each other.

I cannot use `this` or `$(this)` as `$("img.gthumb")` acts as something like event listeners.

Cloning and changing the class names one by one is not a good solution, how can I  use the same javascript and css for multiple elements (in this case is images and titles)? Thanks a lot.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ap94pt9q/1/

Comment: Well you have two divs with a class `.title` both of which get moved to your mouse, you need a better selector to which div is moved. I do not use JQuery so i cannot write based on it. Is your `this` within the handler function set to the image itself? If so use `this.getElementsByClassName('title')[0]` as a selector instead of `$(div.title)` and you are golden

Comment: ^ Won't work since its an image not a div what you are hovering over. But imma edit your fiddle to give you a solution

Comment: The image and the title are under a td tag, the image is not inside the title' s wrapping tag, neither does the image. So as I said, I cannot really use `this`, it is kind of hard. Btw, thanks for the help.

Comment: You can use the `this` to reference the element in the dom tree, look at my answer below, edited your fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$(this).next("div.title")
```

to select the correct `title` - see demo below:

```js
$("img.gthumb").hover(function() {
  $(this).next("div.title").show();
}, function() {
  $(this).next("div.title").hide();
});
$("img.gthumb").mousemove(function(e) {
  var width = $(this).next('div.title').width();
  var height = $(this).next('div.title').height();
  $(this).next("div.title").css("top", e.pageY - height - 5);
  $(this).next("div.title").css("left", e.pageX - width / 2);
});
```

```css
.title {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: large;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<table align="center" border="1" style="overflow:hidden;max-height:177px;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img class="gthumb" src="http://i.imgur.com/V9vL6kg.png" width="175">
      <div class="title">Grand Theft Auto IV
        <br/>俠盜獵車手IV</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="gthumb" src="http://i.imgur.com/V9vL6kg.png" width="175">
      <div class="title">GTA IV
        <br/>to be added</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is simple and fast and this is what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/pm491057/2/

Here you go, though I used native to select the div. Can't JQuery for shiez

```
$("img.gthumb").hover(function() {
  var titleDiv = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('title')[0];
  $(titleDiv).show();
}, function() {
  var titleDiv = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('title')[0];
  $(titleDiv).hide();
});
$("img.gthumb").mousemove(function(e) {
  var titleDiv = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('title')[0];
  var width = $(titleDiv).width();
  var height = $(titleDiv).height();
  $(titleDiv).css("top", e.pageY - height - 5);
  $(titleDiv).css("left", e.pageX - width / 2);
});
```

Comment: This will only work if the `img` and `.title` are wrapped in a single element. If they're all in the same container, this will only ever show the first `.title` element, no matter which `img` you hover over

Comment: Exactly, it will work for the structure he has given, exactly as it is, this is what he asked for. Different scenario, different solution. He wants to avoid IDs, only use classes. You have to put them in the same container.

Comment: I mean it won't work for the structure he has given. If he has one big container that's laid out with `<img class="gthumb" /><div class="title" /><img class="gthumb" /><div class="title" /><img class="gthumb" /><div class="title" /><img class="gthumb" /><div class="title" />`, no matter which `img` tag he hovers over, your code will always select the very first `div.title` of all of them, not the one directly following the `img`. The answer provided by @kukkuz handles it correctly for that scenario.

Comment: Indeed, the code won' t work in @jmcgriz' s case. I will tune the code to fit my expectation. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you'd want to create hoverable elements that contain both the image and the title:

```
<div class="gthumb"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/V9vL6kg.png" width="175"><h2 class="title">Grand Theft Auto IV<br/>俠盜獵車手IV</h2></div>
```

Then, in your `.hover` statement, you can find the title within the element. Right now, using `$("div.title").show()` will show all `.title` elements at the same time, not just the one that you want. So, something like this:

```
$(".gthumb").hover(function () {
  $(this).find(".title").show();
}, function () {
  $(this).find(".title").hide();
});
```

You'll want to update the selectors in your `mousemove` function in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but my problem is that I have already wrote a bunch groups of images and titles. I think I will use `this.parentNode` or `$(this).next()`.

Comment: Yeah, go with the answer provided by @kukkuz, that will handle your current structure with no html changes necessary